# ComboBox inside Gallery

Tags: combobox, save, local-storage, gallery, powerapps

I'm using a gallery to display a list of names I've selected inside the gallery I've inserted a combobox with a bunch of work task codes, this is being saved into a local collection.[Gallery with combobox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9C0MF.png)
when I close the app and re-open it the combobox that is beside each name no longer shows the assigned task code.
I have tried placing the task codes in both the DefaultSelectedItems and Items but can not seem to figure out how to retain the selected code once I reopen the app.
I have a save button with the following **Clear(Myteam); ForAll(Gallery_team.AllItems, Collect(Myteam,{Position:ComboBox_position.Selected.Value})); SaveData(Myteam "Savedteam")**

Answer (score 0):

The use of SaveData is to locally make a save-file of the current state of your collection. It's local, on the device, and not saved somewhere on-prem/cloud related.

If you want to get your SavedDta back into your app, you need to use LoadData first, otherwise the data will stay outside.

For your application, its more wisely to patch it to, for example, a SharePoint list or an excel sheet.

Comment: thank you my issue is only with saving and loading  the combobox selection on appstart i have the Loaddata code. just cant get the combobox value to load.

Comment: How do you perform your loading section?

Comment: on app start - LoadData(MyTeam, "SavedTeam" app is to be used offline, online is  not an option.

Comment: ComboBox_position.Selected.Value, when using comboboxes, look into selecteditems instead.

Comment: am a bit confused with your answers.

Comment: You didn't state the offline requirement. Saving somewhere not local is what PowerApps is best at.
Since you don't want online capabilities, to help you with your storage issue, try the selectedItems function..